# Disable mouse event for a specific child of a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, events, button

I've a MovieClip that contains lot of children.
One of them is a big (and useless) shadow the graphic designer put there to make my life harder (and also the user's one, probably)
:)

Now I'm facing a little issue: the shadow is catching the MouseEvents attached to the main MovieClip (its parent), and this is very bad because it's very distant from the rest of the graphic. I'm now trying to avoid it.

Obviously I've already tried to set the shadow mc's properties `mouseEnabled` and `mouseChildren` to false, but it doesn't work.

I've found a previous thread ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786210/prevent-certain-children-from-affecting-mouseevent-hitbox)), facing the same situation. But the solution accepted looks like it's not working for me.

What I am missing?

Comment: Are you certain that with the `mouseEnabled` and `mouseChildren` set to false on the shadow MovieClip that it is the shadow MovieClip being selected and not one of the numerous other children?

Comment: yes, the shadow is so distant from all the other element that it MUST be it

Comment: Just to be completely 100% certain, have you debugged this code and it has shown that display object was in fact being selected. Perhaps through a trace, identifying the object by name, something along those lines?

Answer (score 2):

If `mouseEnabled` and `mouseChildren` is not working for you then use `e.target.name` property.

But first you will have to give a `name` to that shadow `MovieClip` (say shadowMC).

If you added it dynamically then use,

`yourDynamicMC.name = "shadowMC"`

If added manually on the stage then give instance name as "shadowMC",

Then, inside your code where you have `MouseEvent` function for `parent` `MovieClip` add the following lines

```
if(e.target.name != "shadowMC")
{
    //Then proceed

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question, I am assuming you already tried to set the parent MovieClip's mouseChildren to true with mouseEnabled to false and then set the children's mouseEnabled to true (except for the shadow). This solution should work in my opinion so I am guessing the event might be caught by one parent of your movieclip (you do not give much information about this).

Try to add a listener to the stage to see which object is receiving your MouseEvents:

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(event.target.name, getQualifiedClassName(event.target));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the hit area of your MovieClip. see the MovieClip doc [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#hitArea), this will override you MovieClip zone.